# JavaScript array.slice() behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, slice

I am working on an exercise in learning JavaScript, and cannot figure out why my code is failing a test evaluation. And yes, I realize that I am redundantly (and messily) re-defining Underscore.js *_.last*. That is the purpose of the exercise.

```
_.last = function(array, n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  else {
    return n === undefined ? array.slice(-1) : array.slice(-n);
  };
}'
```

These are the results I get when running:

```
_.last([1,2,3], 2)
[2, 3]
_.last([1,2,3], 5)
[1, 2, 3]
_.last([1,2,3], 0)
[]
_.last([1,2,3])
[3]
```

The very last call *_.last([1,2,3])* is the one failing this evaluation:

```
expect(_.last([1,2,3])).to.equal(3)
```

Can anyone tell why this expect is returning false? What am I overlooking

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: solved.
else edited to return value if n===undefined rather than returning a single-value array:

```
return n === undefined ? array[array.length-1] : array.slice(-n);
```

Comment: So you're expecting it to return `3`, but receive an array with the entry 3. i.d. `[3]`?

Comment: I'm going to assume it's because `[ 3 ] !== 3`

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes sense. I was actually wondering if that might be the case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.slice` returns an array. And if you compare an array and a number, they will be different.

Instead, consider doing the same underscore [does](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-53):

```js
if (n == null /*|| guard*/) return array[array.length - 1];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had checked out the underscore docs, and the *|| guard* was throwing me off. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you and @taxicala answered too quickly. I can't mark this as solved for another 4 minutes. :P

Answer (score 0):

Quoting array.slice description:

> The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new
>   array object.

Basically, your code is ok, and your test is not:

You should change:

```
expect(_.last([1,2,3])).to.equal(3)
```

to:

```
expect(_.last([1,2,3])).to.equal([3])
```

More info here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp